# Why is this jquery reloading the whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can see below where I am trying to diagnose what is happening when I hit `ENTER` while the cursor is in my `INPUT` box.

Here is my input box.

```
<input type="text" name="addtolist" id = "input" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```

and here is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   

    $('.delete').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    });

    $('.check').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("inactive");
    });

    $('#input').keyup(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 13){
            console.log("lsdkfj");
        };
    });
});
```

And all that is happening is my page reloads -- which is awesome, but F5 already does that for me. Why the reload instead of `console.log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is in a form, the default event when pressing enter is to submit the form. So you need to prevent the default behavior first:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now your `keyup` event should work. Then when you want to submit the form you can attach an event to some element and submit like so:

```
$('form').submit();
```

Comment: So taking the input box out of the form tags solves everything. I'm looking around at pages about forms, but I still can't find a clear answer as to why one should ever use them. Why not skip them all together? Maybe forms should only be used if you want to send multiple answers simultaneously?

Comment: Forms are very useful tags because they describe how the server will process the request. AJAX libraries like jQuery work with your forms as well. But if your input is isolated and has nothing to do with retrieving data, then no, you don't need a form.

Comment: Not just retrieving, but posting data too. There are forms that have only one field, like a subscribe form.

Comment: Thanks. I'm beginning to see the difference. But I'm still wondering if forms is an old method, and there are newer javascript methods that supersede it. It's hard to tell the difference when you're learning html and javascript at the same time.

Comment: There are several reasons why to use forms. This is standardized way of sending data to server, so they should be intuitive to your users no matter what browser or OS they are using. That's why enter key behave as it is and so on.. Also, not everyone necessarily has to have enabled javascript or have browser with AJAX support. One more huge deal is about accessibility, imagine a blind person using a screen reader on your page. If you are using a form, he will be informed about it and he will know where he is and how to use it... So on, so forth, standards are good to use if you can!

Comment: Even if you don't care about accessibility forms are still better than no forms, because you can describe their behavior with attributes in a declarative way. It's like trying to create a link without using `<a>`; it's doable but you'd simply use the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Hitting enter submits the form. You need to cancel the event properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is probably in the form and if so, this is default behavior for forms, to prevent this you need to

```
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(){return false});
```